# Why is the growth in value of ADA being described as "parabolic" rather than "exponential" or something else?

Tags: ada, terminology

Here I list multiple articles since March 2021 that have described ADA's value as undergoing a "parabolic" trajectory:

- **26 March 2021:** [Cardano Technical Analysis: ADA Has Flipped The Parabolic SAR From Bullish To Bearish](https://trading-education.com/cardano-technical-analysis-ada-has-flipped-the-parabolic-sar-from-bullish-to-bearish-021821)
- **17 March 2021:** [Cardano Is a Rising Altcoin Star, but the Payoff May Be Years Away](https://investorplace.com/2021/03/cardano-rising-star-payoff-years-away/)
- **2 April 2021:** [An Emerging Trend Could Mean Wild Prices Ahead for Cardano](https://investorplace.com/2021/04/cardano-emerging-trend-could-mean-wild-prices-ahead/)

In the field of **stocks and securities**, the term "[parabolic SAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_SAR)" was coined [in 1978](https://archive.org/details/newconceptsintec00wild) by J. Welles Wilder Jr. (who unfortunately died 9 days ago by the way).

**In the cryptocurrency community, why is ADA's growth seemingly always being described as "parabolic" rather than "exponential" or following some other type of growth curve?**

Answer (score 6):

Searching Google for "cardano ada exponential" gives ~305k results.

Searching Google for "cardano ada parabolic" gives ~309k results.

Likely is just some resistance in the community to the mass-media habit of applying the adjective "exponential" for any sort of super-linear growth.  I don't *know* that parabolic is a better adjective, but it seems to be adapted by the community.

Comment: Thanks! The fact that "parabolic" is used more than "exponential" despite those search results showing "exponential" way more if you remove the "cardano ada" part, is what alarms me. These functions are ***very*** different, so I wondered if there was some actual basis  for the choice of term, such as J. Welles Wilder Jr's definition based on "Parabolic SAR".